# Ruby on Rails Dirty method _was not working with serialized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class WorkRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :upload, :assigned_to_staff
  serialize :assigned_to_staff, Array

  before_save :set_old_staff
  def set_old_staff
    @old_staff = self.assigned_to_staff_was
  end

  def staff_changed?
    !self.assigned_to_staff.empty? && self.assigned_to_staff != @old_staff
  end
end
```

I'm trying to make use of self.assigned_to_was to track when a staff assignment change takes place. I'm noticing that the serialized field behaves differently than a regular field. Console output below shows differing behavior in :upload (text string field) and the serialized :assigned_to_staff:

```
1.9.2-p320 :002 > wr.upload
 => nil 
1.9.2-p320 :003 > wr.upload_was
 => nil 
1.9.2-p320 :004 > wr.upload = "Yes"
 => "Yes" 
1.9.2-p320 :005 > wr.upload_was
 => nil
```

compared to:

```
1.9.2-p320 :006 > wr.assigned_to_staff
 => [] 
1.9.2-p320 :007 > wr.assigned_to_staff_was
 => [] 
1.9.2-p320 :008 > wr.assigned_to_staff << User.last.name
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => ["last5, first5"] 
1.9.2-p320 :009 > wr.assigned_to_staff_was
 => ["last5, first5"]
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy and or suggest a workaround?

Comment: Using assignment seems to rectify this issue, even if it does reduce the convenience of the serialization. wr.assigned_to_staff = [User.last.name] sets the variable correctly and leaves wr.assigned_to_staff as [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that serialization doesn't fully implement all methods of the host class. Overrides are provided for getters and setters, but not concatenation.